# How to use Row_Number in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image]

I want the below output to use `Row_Number` in a query to add one column RowNo.

[image]

I have used the following query but did not get output.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DetailId ORDER BY DetailId) AS RowNum,
    Masterid,
    DetailId 
FROM 
    #DATA
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks fine, so I suspect the issue might be sorting the results:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DetailId ORDER BY DetailId) AS RowNum,
       Masterid, DetailId 
FROM #DATA
ORDER BY RowNum, DetailId;
```

Another possibility is that you are looking for duplicates of both columns, in which case:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DetailId, MasterId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum,
       Masterid, DetailId 
FROM #DATA
ORDER BY RowNum, DetailId, MasterId;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using SQL ROW_NUMBER() to find duplicate values:**
There are many possible ways to write this query for this particular question I believe.

*Simple SQL ROW_NUMBER()*: the query uses the ROW_NUMBER() function to add sequential integer numbers to each row.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY RowNum DESC
    ) 
    RowNo, 
    Masterid, 
    DetailId 
FROM
   #DATA
WHERE
   MasterId = 46681;
```

*Using subquery:*
First, use the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign each row a sequential integer number. Second, filter rows by requested page.

```
SELECT RowNo,
       MasterId,
       DetailId
 FROM (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetailId) RowNo, 
             MasterId, 
            DetailId,
           
        FROM
           #DATA
        ) t    
    WHERE
       MasterId = 46681;
```

And by *PARTITION BY* method:

```
 SELECT 
       RowNo,
       MasterId,
       DetailId
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                RowNo,
                `ROW_NUMBER()` OVER (
                    PARTITION BY RowNo
                    ORDER BY DetailId DESC)
                RowNo, 
                MasterId, 
                DetailId
      
            FROM 
                #DATA
               
        ) t
    WHERE 
       MasterId = 46681;
```

Comment: Is there a need for subquery? Cant you add `WHERE` clause directly?

Comment: You should explain your answers and code only answers are considered as low quality and hard to understand by others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).